# Laravel 5 wildcard subdomain + route model binding

Tags: php, laravel

So when you define a resource controller in a wildcard subdomain group route similar to this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'), function() {
  Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

on RouteServiceProvider

```
$router->model('user', 'App\User');
```

and on the UserController show method:

```
public function show($user)
{
    return $user;
}
```

what i get is the subdomain name instead of the user resource. This is because the `subdomain` parameter is passed to controller methods and i would have to change them like this:

```
public function show($subdomain, $user)
{
    return $user;
}
```

I simply don't want to add the subdomain parameter to each and every controller method in my app because i am not going to do anything with it. I use the subdomain parameter in a middleware to do some configuration changes.

How can i do it so the subdomain doesn't get passed to controllers as parameter?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: I gave up and ended up including the subdomain parameter on every controller method. Came up to be handy for some cases though. Especially when i needed to pass the parameter to the views.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this question is somewhat old (and potentially stale) although I stumbled across this post when searching for an answer to *another* route model binding question.

To avoid requiring the subdomain, you can specify that Laravel forgets that route parameter.

You could either do this in a middleware (which checks for the subdomain too), like so:

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('subdomain');
```

Alternatively, using your code snippet, it would look something along the lines of this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com'), function() {
  Route::forgetParameter('subdomain');
  Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

However, I'd strongly recommend that the process is moved into a middleware, as it doesn't feel right putting that in the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller function you can ignore the $dubdomain if you do not use it and make sure you typehint the User like this

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Margus. That makes sense but it doesn't feel like a good way of doing it. It may cause confusion for nested resources. I prefer to simply make router ignore the subdomain parameter.

Comment: I just tested and you can ignore the $subdomain if you do not use it. As you have User then you need to typehint it to be resolved.

Comment: I get `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\UserController::show() must be an instance of App\User, string given` when i typehint User. Assuming that string is the subdomain passed.

Comment: It must be something related to model binding then and needs deeper investigation. I am able to typehint and get resolved Eloquent Model values and skip other url params.

Comment: @MargusPala how to solve it if there is a model binding on route service provider? Perhaps you have this `$router->bind('users', function($id) { return \App\User::findOrFail($id); });` and on methods there is already the type hint doSomething(User $user) { ... again laravel asks for object and the subdomain is taking place of it.